# convert multiple canvases to dataURL in html5

Tags: javascript, html

I want to join multiple canvases to make a single image. 
So is there any method to covert more than one canvases to `toDataURL` to make a single image?

Comment: You can copy all canvases' drawings into a larger temporary canvas and then call `toDataURL()` of the later.

Comment: thnx @Ammar can you provide me the reference plz

Comment: @Muhammad Usmar: Answer provided by `bennedich` below is the same approach I was talking about. Use `drawImage()` function of canvas. For any further difficulties let us know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this example hope it will help see  [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-loader/)

```
                //html block


                <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">


                </canvas>
                <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
                Your browser does not support the canvas element.
                </canvas>

                <canvas id="Canvasimage" width="500" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
                Your browser does not support the canvas element.
                </canvas>
    <img id="finalimage" width="500" height="100"  style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"/>

                //script block
                function loadImages(sources, callback) {
                    var images = {};
                    var loadedImages = 0;
                    var numImages = 0;
                    // get num of sources
                    for (var src in sources) {
                        numImages++;
                    }
                    for (var src in sources) {
                        images[src] = new Image();
                        images[src].onload = function () {
                            if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                                callback(images);
                            }
                        };
                        images[src].src = sources[src];
                    }
                }

                window.onload = function (images) {

            //Canvas first  here
                    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
                    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
                 //Canvas second here
                    var c1 = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
                    var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
                    ctx1.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
                    ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 100);


               //Canvas final here.
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvasimage");
                    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

                    var sources = {
                        darthVader: c.toDataURL("image/png"),
                        yoda: c1.toDataURL("image/png")
                    };

                    loadImages(sources, function (images) {
                        context.drawImage(images.darthVader, 100, 30, 200, 137);
                        context.drawImage(images.yoda, 350, 55, 93, 104);
//finalimage  here which has two canvas data
                var finalimage = document.getElementById("finalimage");
        finalimage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); 
                    });
                };
```

Comment: no. there is one canvas and multiple images. I need multiple canvases

Answer (score 5):

create a function that takes multiple arguments (canvas elements), puts them on one blank canvas, then returns the dataurl for the newly made canvas.

```
var getImadeData = function () {
    var i = arguments.length,
        tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
        ctx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
     while (i--) {
        ctx.drawImage(arguments[i], 0, 0);
    };
    return tempCanvas.toDataURL();
};
```

Now just feed the function multiple canvas elements you want to put into one dataurl like so.

```
var newData = getImageData(canvas1, canvas2, canvas3);
```

In this example, the last canvas is placed on the blank canvas first so make sure to order your canvas elements appropriately.

Comment: please provide some explanations along with the code. That way future visitors will know what they are looking and you might receive more upvotes for your contributions

Comment: I added some explanation, but it honestly feels a bit superfluous.  Was there something in particular that you felt needed more detail?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the `drawImage` method on the canvas 2d rendering context accepts canvas elements as image elements. So all you have to do is:

- Create a new canvas
- Get its context
- Draw all other canvases to it with `drawImage`
- Extract the final image from this new canvas