# Making image from multiple canvases

Tags: javascript, canvas, printing

how to make one single IMG from multiple canvases? I want to make button to my web app that will make one single image from more overlaid canvases. I found this option but i don´t know how to make it work with multiple canvases to single image.
Thank you

```
function print() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert multiple canvases to dataURL in html5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929067/convert-multiple-canvases-to-dataurl-in-html5)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to have 1 canvas with multiple fragments of the same image?

Answer (score 3):

Simply draw the canvases into your main canvas:

Assuming they have id's:

```
var canvasMain = document.getElementById('canvasMain'); //destination canvas
var ctx = canvasMain.getContext('2d');

var canvas1 = document.getElementById('canvas1');       // layer 1
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');       // layer 2
var canvas3 = document.getElementById('canvas3');       // layer 3

ctx.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0);    // draw canvas 1 into main canvas
ctx.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0);    // draw canvas 2 into main canvas
ctx.drawImage(canvas3, 0, 0);    // draw canvas 3 into main canvas

var dataUri = canvasMain.toDataURL(); //extract main canvas as url
```

Hope this helps!